# How to post to a form using <a> tag and passing hidden value?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, laravel-4

If I had some coding as follow.

```
<form method="POST" action="localhost/carts/delete">
  <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Item 3</a>
</form>
```

And I like to post to a form with some hidden value to indicate which Item is clicked, how to do that???

Thanks.

Edited Text.

Thanks for so many useful suggestions.

I actually use Laravel 4 rather than PHP, my Laravel code produced this HTML

```
<form ...>
  <ul>
    <li> 
      <h1>Key: 1 </h1>
      <input name="cart_id" type="hidden" value="1"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Delete</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <h1>Key: 2 </h1>
      <input name="cart_id" type="hidden" value="2"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Delete</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <h1>Key: 6 </h1>
      <input name="cart_id" type="hidden" value="6"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Delete</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <h1>Key: 7 </h1>
      <input name="cart_id" type="hidden" value="7"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

So, when I clicked on any items, I got 7 which is the last value of cart_id, how to place  at the right place, in JavaScript???

Comment: Can you use `input type="button"` instead?

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'm using jQuery Mobile so I really need to use <a> tag, otherwise I cannot get the expected UI style.

Comment: @TusharGupta There is no errors yet, but I don't get the concept of how to pass hidden field value according to clicked <a>, so I don't what to code next. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden element inside the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="localhost/carts/delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="myValue" value="" id="myValue"/>

    <a href="#" data-value="1">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-value="2">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-value="3">Item 3</a>
</form>
```

Then on click over any link (`a`) change its value and submit the form.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    //preventing the default link redirection
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#myValue').val($(this).data('value'));
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this now, I will let you know later.

Comment: This is pure JS or jQuery???, sorry for this stupid question but I really don't know.

Comment: @Kongthap is jQuery. As you added it on the tags I hope there's no problem with it.

Comment: With your coding, when click on the <a> link of any items, I cannot not make it post yet, I put the old <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">XXX</a> just in case, fortunately clicking on this link make a post to the form.

Comment: the JS coding is inside <script></script> at the bottom of the page outside the <form></form>

Comment: @Kongthap It works well. It post the info. Take a look at this living demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/tKcCM/ Make sure your code is inside the [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

Comment: Before it was about document.ready(), now the post happens but no values passing to the controller, at least if clicked on the XXX, I should get "0" but I just get null, my entire old coding I can get the "7" which is the last value. http://jsfiddle.net/jeud/BthpP/1/

Comment: @Kongthap you didn't apply my code correctly... the input named `card_id` should have an id attribute `id="card_id"` because that's the selector used in jQuery. `#` means `id` tag, not `name`...

Comment: @Kongthap also, you are not creating the `data-value` attribute for the link... look at my code again...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I don't understand what you meant by "I'm not creating the "data-value" attribute for the link. http://jsfiddle.net/jeud/BthpP/3/ I tried to read you code several times but I didn't get what you tried to tell me.

Comment: @Kongthap dont you see that my links has an attribute `data-value` ?

Comment: I can see it, but mine also has data-value too, <a href="#" data-value="1">Delete Item 1</a>, I meant, I can find something else, is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden input field like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="hidden value" name="id"/>
```

This box is not visible in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Use input fields instead.

```
<form method="POST" action="localhost/carts/delete">
  <input type="submit" value="Item 1" name="whichitem[]" />
  <input type="submit" value="Item 2" name="whichitem[]" />
  <input type="submit" value="Item 2" name="whichitem[]" />
</form>
```

Then in PHP you can retrieve the clicked value like this:

```
$_POST["whichitem"]
```

If you are worried about the styling, simply add it in your css:

```
input[type="submit"]{
   //style
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only can use <a> because I expect specific looking with jQuery Mobile.